# How to Print in Landscape Mode with Open Office Calc

Tags: printing, openoffice

I have three `.ods` files that I am trying to print using `ver 4.14`.  It wants to print on 2 pages.  I select

- Print Selected Cells
- Landscape Orientation

However, it still prints on two pages rather than combining them into one.  In landscape mode, they will easily fit on one page.

A similar process normally works on MS Office.  How do get  **OO** to print on one page in landscape mode.

These are the only options I see.  Under Properties I have already change the orientation to Landscape.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- File > Page Preview
- Format Page button at top
- In the Page tab, change Orientation from Portrait to Landscape
- You can adjust the scaling factor slider and margins on the page preview to make it fit
- Print

It seems to remember this setting when just using the regular print option now, but I am not sure why the setting isn't available in the main print settings.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, since they are largely interchangeable, In Libre, this IS in the print dialog [Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YIPf.png)

Not sure if that is an option for you, seems a major change for a minor inconvenience, but it S there, and cost the same thing (Nada)!